# PyBlueZ bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port

I am currently 'playing' with bluetooth devices the objective is to send data (just a text string) from a raspberryPi2 to an Android smartphone.

Let me add that i am aware of the existence of the so-called 'pairing' process, and discovery. I have been able to successfully send data from the phone to my computer (windows 10). 
However i cannot recieve or send data to and from the RaspberryPi and phone.
In Windows: can only recieve data from phone but cannot send to it.

the code ( to RECIEVE, on the computer) i use is the following:

```
from bluetooth import *
server_socket=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_socket.bind(("", 3))
server_socket.listen(1)

client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

data = client_socket.recv(1024)

print("received [%s]" % data)

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

On the phone i use an app called "Bluetooth terminal"

in this app i must first "connect" the phone to my computer. This is where i have my 2nd question:

What does it really mean to "connect" 2 bluetooth devices ? 
-> it doesn't look like pairing
-> it is even more confusing as i can sometimes "directly" send to the phone without have to go through this mysterious "connection" process....

what do they mean by "connecting"?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i think i can answer my own question:

from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#about-uuid

Note that there is a difference between being paired and being connected:

To be paired means that two devices are aware of each other's existence, have a shared link-key that can be used for authentication, and are capable of establishing an encrypted connection with each other.

To be **connected** means that the devices currently share an RFCOMM channel and are able to transmit data with each other. The current Android Bluetooth API's require devices to be paired before an RFCOMM connection can be established. Pairing is automatically performed when you initiate an encrypted connection with the Bluetooth APIs.